# 'ASP.Facebook' does not contain a definition for 'FacebookSettings'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, razor, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK.
My site was working fine yesterday.

This morning on running a build I'm getting:

> 'ASP.Facebook' does not contain a definition for 'FacebookSettings'

I've no ideas what caused this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok undid what i did yesterday which was to basically install the microsoft web helper package from nuget.
not sure why this conflicted -  perhaps there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a change in the SDK from 4.x to 5.x

The methods to access the Facebook settings from the config file changed, so your code should change from this:

```
FB.init({ appId: '<%:FacebookSettings.Current.AppId %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
```

to this:

```
FB.init({ appId: '<%: Facebook.FacebookContext.Current.AppId %>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but im still using the 4.X SDK.